# SQL Issue With Joins

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have looked at the examples and I think that the word `Login` is the problem. Is this an internal command word in SQL? Here is what I am trying to do.

- Table 1 is `Login` and has `LoginID` and `LoginName`
- Table 2 is `LoginGroup` and has `LoginID` and `GroupID`

I want to join the two so that I can get a list of `LoginNames` for a specific `GroupID`.

I have tried many different iterations and solutions on this and other sites, but cant seem to find the right combination. Here is my most recent attempt:

```
SELECT Login.LoginName AS login_name
FROM Login
INNER JOIN login on login.loginid = LoginGroup.LoginID
WHERE LoginGroup.LoginID = 9230
```

This produces:

> Msg 1013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The objects "login" and "Login" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Can someone tell me what this needs to look like?

Answer (score 0):

on your inner join you need to do:

```
FROM Login
INNER JOIN LoginGroup on Login.LoginID = LoginGroup.LoginID
```

you join tables two tables and then specify what columns in the tables to match on.  It appears you were trying to join table straight to column.